# How can I make a wrapper function for discord.py commands?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, wrapper

I have been trying to crate the wrapper @validate_channel, this wrapper should make the command only run if executed on a server and not on a private channel, I am trying:

Command function:

```
@validate_channel
@bot.command(brief="Adds one or more members to the whitelist")
async def add(ctx: commands.Context, *users: discord.Member):
    if not check_permissions(ctx.author.id, ctx.guild):
        await ctx.send(NOT_ALLOWED_MSG)
    else:
        config = get_config(ctx.guild.id)
        allowed_users = config.get('allowed-users', [])
        if not users:
            await ctx.send(f"You didn't specify any users!")
            return
        for user in users:
            if user.id not in allowed_users:
                allowed_users.append(user.id)
        config['allowed-users'] = allowed_users
        update_config(ctx.guild.id, config)
        await ctx.send(f"Added {', '.join(user.name for user in users)} to the whitelist!")
```

Wrapper:

```
def validate_channel(func):
    async def inner(ctx: commands.Context, message, *args, **kwargs):
        if ctx.channel.type is discord.ChannelType.private:
            await ctx.send("This command cannot be run from direct messages.")
        else:
            return func

    return inner
```

But it just doesn't seem to work, no matter what I try, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning `inner` you should use [`commands.check`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.check) instead

```py
def validate_channel():
    async def inner(ctx):
        if not ctx.channel.type is discord.ChannelType.private:  # or even better `not isinstance(ctx.channel, discord.DMChannel)`
            await ctx.send("You cannot use this command in DMs")
            return False
        return True   
   return commands.check(inner)


@validate_channel()
@bot.command()
async def ...
```

A better, shorter and easier way is to use the [`commands.dm_only`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.dm_only) check:

```py
@commands.dm_only()
@bot.command()
async def ...
```

Comment: Thank you!
Thanks to your comment I found about discord.py checks and how to use them, I managed to clean up my code and also implement the feature I asked for in this question :)